# Getting XML error in IE11 but not in other browsers

Tags: json, xml, jsf, richfaces, internet-explorer-11

I'm using JSF in my application. In one of the tags `<a4j:function>` I'm using data attribute to get JSON data from server. the data is huge. It renders fine in Mozilla and Chrome as well as in IE9 but IE11 throws XML error.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="getData"
                execute="@this"
                data="#{userBean.managedObjectsList}" 
                oncomplete="setTreeData();">
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

When I call `getData()` method,it throws XML error.
Below is the error:

> XML5686: Unspecified XML error. Line: 219585, Column 8

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is my ajax function :-                                                                 <a4j:jsFunction name="getData" execute="@this" data="#{userBean.changeData}" oncomplete="setTreeData();"></a4j:jsFunction>

Comment: Anything specific at or around line 219585, column 8?

Comment: It works fine with lesser data being sent from server.

Comment: I'm not able to get the response for it as it refreshes the page by itself whenever i try to see the response body in ie11.

Comment: it can be replicated in local as well....we need to write similar function and the  function should return huge amount of data.if we open the application in ie 11.then we can see the error